# Specify Order When Using merge=union in gitattributes

Tags: git

I have a changelog in a project. I want to use `merge=union` in [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for this file. Is there a way to also tie in the concept of `ours` and `theirs` like in [Git Tools - Advanced Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging)? I want `theirs` to always be at the top

development branch:

```
* Added Feature in development branch
* Added Feature Y
* Added Feature X
```

master:

```
Version 1.0
===
* Added Feature Z
* Added Feature Y
* Added Feature X
```

I am trying to avoid the situation where `Added Feature in development branch` was not introduced until after 1.0, but the changelog would show up something like this:

```
Version 1.0
===
* Added Feature Z
* Added Feature in development branch
* Added Feature Y
* Added Feature X
```

I want it to instead show up something like:

```
* Added Feature in development branch

Version 1.0
===
* Added Feature Z
* Added Feature Y
* Added Feature X
```

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution to this?

Comment: No I did not. I dropped it.

Answer (score 1):

Union merge has no control knob for which parts come out where.

You can write your own merge driver that does have such a control knob.